# 64-bit Qt and Postgres plugin in Windows

Tags: windows, qt, postgresql, 64-bit

I have a 32-bit Windows/Qt application using Postgres plugin. Recently, I've been intrigued to turn the app into a 64-bit app. So I checked the Qt docs for instructions, built Qt and its libraries into 64-bit successfully. Now the problem is Postgres does not provide libraries for 64-bit Windows! Obviously, the Qt Postgres plugin won't compile. I googled around a lot and didn't find any solutions, just a whole bunch of non-helpful discussion archive postings. So, is there a way for me to compile my app as true 64-bit while using Postgres in Windows?

**ADDENUM**
The problem isn't running Postgres as true 64-bit on Windows ([which cannot be done](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/73-PostgreSQL-vs-64-bit-windows.html)) (I'm not managing the database, so I don't care even), but to compile my Qt app as 64-bit (which very much gains from being true 64-bit). But since it needs to access Postgres DB, I can't do it, Qt Postgres plugin will not compile and I won't have DB access.

So, should I just separate Postgres related stuff to a 32-bit DLL (can I use 32-bit dlls with 64-bit app even?), or even to a separate executable, or can I use some other framework for accessing it...?

**Give me any, even dirty, solution** to this problem and state the pros and cons it may have and what else it might affect or break.

Comment: There's no way to compile Postgres as a 64-bit Windows executable?

Comment: See this pgsql-hackers thread: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2008-07/msg00081.php
There is a lot of issues with 64-bit Postgres on Windows despite 64-bit Linux version works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm about to get Vista 64 on my work machine so I was looking this up as well.

Basically - No, Postrgresql will not compile in Windows 64bit (yet), though it has worked for years in *nix 64bit.

I found this [link](http://blog.hagander.net/archives/73-PostgreSQL-vs-64-bit-windows.html) - from one of the maintainers of the Windows installer.

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I wrote an addenum to the question, maybe you have information about that?